# How to get the real height of a character (fontmetrics/graphics2d)

Tags: graphics2d, fontmetrics

I am currently in need to get the real height of a character. I am aware of the functions like getDecsent(), getAscent(), ... but they only allow to get values regarding the hole font (in its context). I also tried the way using getStringBounds(), but that is the same story.

Like the title says, I am looking for a way to get the height value of just one char at a time.

For example 'N' is higher then 'n', 'I' just a little bit higher then 'i' and so on

Thanks for your time

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can help by elaborating your question a bit more. By hight did you mean the pixel height?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I mean Pixel height.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Rectangle2D bounds = font.getStringBounds("put your string here", context);
//font can be set to whatever you want
//my suggestion is that you use the same font for both characters
//context is a object of FontRenderContext
System.out.println(bounds.getHeight());
//Instead of just printing it you could do this a second time and compare the 2 strings
```